# How to add Dictionary values to a Collection in C#?

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# test and in here I have `ICollection<ProductVariant>` and ProductVariant has name field which is a Dictionary. I want to have multiple ProductVariants for my testing.

what I have done is

```cs
ICollection<ProductVariant> productVariants = new Collection<ProductVariant>();
```

Now I want to add different product variants to this collection

```cs
productVariant.Add(new ProductVariant()
{
// I want to initialize Name here which is a dictionary

Name = new Dictionary<string, string>("var1", "variant1")
};
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Define "not working"? Are you getting error messages? If so, what do they say

Comment: You should probably tell us what your data looks like, your approach doesn't look like the way you should go with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inline initialization for dictionary looks a bit different

```
productVariant.Add(new ProductVariant()
{ 
    Name = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "var1", "variant1" },
        { "var2", "variant1" }
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you could assign local variable to a property. I like this approach more because of good stacktrace in case of error

```
var nameDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
nameDict.Add("var1", "variant1");
nameDict.Add("var2", "variant1");

productVariant.Add(new ProductVariant()
{ 
    Name = nameDict
};
```

Comment: Indeed. OP needs a _nested initializer_. There is no `Dictionary` constructor that takes key & value for one element, nor would such a thing really make sense.